# Cross domain post request using jquery/ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form like this

```
<form id= 'frm_request'>
<table class="opt_tbl1" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td><strong>TLD No.</strong></td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="tldno" name="tldno" size="25" maxlength="25"  />
      </td>  </tr>
  <tr >   <td><strong>Name of Worker</strong></td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size=50 maxlength=50 /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ><strong>Date of Birth (Optional)</strong></td>
    <td ><input id="new_day" name="dateofbirth" type="text" />

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="center"><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="_btn" value="Submit" action=""/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

When the focus moves from input box “tldno”, the input  “fname” to be filled by  getting  the html from another domain which I have no control. The html in the other domain, is like this:

```
<body>
<form method="POST" name="form1" action="../dbms/allindvres.asp" target="I1">
  <table >
    <tr>
      <td width="33%" height="22" align="middle" ><font size=4>TLD No &nbsp;<input name="TLDNO" size="10"></td>
      <td width="33%" height="22" align="middle" ><font size=4>CC No &nbsp;<input name="CCNO" size="10"></td>
      <td width="33%" height="22" align="middle"><font size=4>or Name &nbsp;<input name="name" size="30"></td>
      <td width="33%" height="22" align="middle">
        <p align="center">< <input type="submit" value="Get Life Dose" name="B1"></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<iframe name="I1" >
Your browser does not support inline frames or is currently configured not to display inline frames.</iframe></p></p>

</body>
```

Upon submitting the above form, the result will be displayed in the iframe. I want the whole html in my page  so that I can scrap traverse through the html to get the name of the tldno holder and display it in my input box.  Kindly help me to write an ajax call that will return this html

```
$("#tldno").blur(function(e){

// ajax POST call to the URL  http://10.40.64.100/dbms/allindvres.asp  with  parameter  tldno
//Get html 
//do something with this html – This part I know.
});
```

Can any one help with the above method or suggest alternate methods?
Two important points in this question is, (1) I do not have control on the other domain.  (2) the URL on the other domain accepts only POST not GET

Comment: form ID should be small like id

Comment: you can develop a proxy server in your web server where you will send an ajax request to your webserver which will forward the request to the designated external server using a http client then once the response from the external sever comes back sent it back to your ajax client